# SQL statement in Java to sort by date (month)

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, calendar

I have an SQL table in my Android project, that has a KEY_DATE field in **Date** format.

> KEY_DATE + " DATE,"

My table is populated from the java code (date in *dd/mm/yy* format).
So now I need to make several date-related queries and something isn't working.
I need to make selections from a table for today, this month and this year.
Here's what I tried:

```
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
     Date todayD = new Date();
     dateFormat.format(todayD);
     String today = dateFormat.format(todayD);

     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
     Date firstDay = cal.getTime();
     dateFormat.format(firstDay); 

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PAYMENTS + "WHERE " 
    +  KEY_DATE +" BETWEEN " + firstDay + " AND " + today;
```

The query returns empty even though there's a lot of data for that period.
I believe something is wrong with data formats here. Can you  help me to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Print out `selectQuery` and the answer should be obvious.

Comment: I would to recommend to always use ISO format for dates when writing queries (yyyy-MM-dd). You should quote the date too, otherwise it will be interpreted as a division operation. And when dealing with date ranges, it is better to use "date >= firstDay and date < lastDay+1". Your "today" will be interpreted as 0:00:00 from the date, so you will only retrieve data for the first second of the day. If you want to retrieve data for the whole day, you need to query for "before midnight of tomorrow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not formatting `firstD`, so you only get from the first day of the month *at the current time* on;
2. You should either use single quotes around the dates in your queries or use prepared statements, otherwise your server will understand your dates as math operations;
3. When querying for date ranges, remember that if you don't specify an hour with your date SQL will by default take it as zero hour (0:00:00.0000). If you use "between startDate and today", you get only midnight of today. If you use "between startDate and tomorrow", you get midnight of tomorrow too. You should use "date >= startDate and date < tomorrow" to get the proper range.
4. When writing queries with dates, I always prefer to use ISO format for the date strings: yyyy-MM-dd.

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

   Date todayD = new Date();
   cal.setTime(todayD);
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   Date tomorrowD = cal.getTime();
   String today = dateFormat.format(tomorrowD);

   cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   Date firstD = cal.getTime();
   String firstDay = dateFormat.format(firstD);

   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE_PAYMENTS WHERE KEY_DATE >= '" + firstDay + "' AND KEY_DATE < '" + today + "'";

Comment: The # 3 item is known as “Half-Open” approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. A wise way to go for defining spans of time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the date formats for the data present inside the database and the date formats that you are passing (strings) to the sql query.

It is not a good practice to pass **dates as string parameters** to the sql query, so I strongly suggest use `preparedStatement` as shown below:

```
Date todayD = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Date firstDay = cal.getTime();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE_PAYMENTS WHERE BETWEEN ? AND ?" ;

//create preparedStatement here

preparedStatement.setDate(1, firstDay);
preparedStatement.setDate(2, todayD);
```

Comment: Good answer except for using the troublesome old date-time types. JDBC drivers that comply with JDBC 4.2 and later can deal directly with the java.time types via `ResultSet::getObject` and `PreparedStatement::setObject` methods.